# Plenty of missing python package

Tags: python, module

In my whole life, when I installed a software, his dependancies link has installed all the python things that he needs to, so it can run right after the installation

But now on my PC, I don't know what i've done, but I can install, uninstall, reinstall, all python package or parent package that ask for it, but it doesn't changes anything: When I launch softwares, they complain indefinitely on missing modules. So I can install what he asks but I have to install manually ALL the modules that all my softwares ask for ONE BY ONE.

What i've done? It wasnt like that before

How do I manage for the modules to install normally and automatically, like it naturally was?

Comment: How do you install packages? Pip?

Comment: I was used to install the softwares with my package manager, and he handeled all the dependencies just right, I never had missing modules. Now I do like always but theres missing module all over. And when I tried to install the modules to resolve this problem I was doing it with my package manager too, and it resolve the dependency, but there plenty of them just after, so I have to reinstall the whole ever maked modules by hand one by one and reexecute the sotfware to see. Isn't there a way to return at what it was, automatic?

Comment: tl;dr: all with package manager

Comment: Don’t know what package manager it is, on what operating system, but did the default Python version change from 2 to 3 or something? All operating systems are making that change at some point

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager ; on Linux, I don't know about the default version of Python

Comment: What is your operating system? Windows 10? MacOS 10.15? Ubuntu 20.04? And what is the package manager that you use for the Python packages? Pip? Apt? Synaptic? What are the commands that you give to the package manager, and what are the exact error messages you get?

Comment: I use `pacman`, I give him `pacman -Syu $SOFTWARE_THAT_RELIES_ON_PYTHON` and it gives me no errors

Answer (score 0):

I tried something that seems to work so far

I did a

```bsh
for i in `pacman -Q  | cut -f 1 -d ' '`; do pactree $i | grep unresolvable >> unmetDependencies; done
```

To get a list of missing packages; Then some

```bsh
cat unmetDependencies | sed {─;├;└;│; ;[unresolvable]} > unmetDependencies
```

(thats not the real command, I did it instead with a "Search and replace" on a WYSIWYG) to get only the packages name; a

```bsh
sort unmetDependencies | uniq > unmetDependencies
```

to only have packages names once; and finally a

```bsh
pacman --asdeps -Sy `cat unmetDependencies`
```

To install those

(I imagine that on Ubuntu it's simple because apt-get has an option to resolve all the system unmet dependencies)

---

(for real it doesn't resolves everything, for example, I have `libxml2` installed but softwares stills ask for it. However it still resolves some problems. It's maybe a problem of path or idk, but python doesn't find some modules. But basically if you reinstall all package of your OS it should work fine)

I found a command who seems to display packages who have problems and I reinstalled those listed packages:

```bsh
pacman -Syu `pacman -Qkq | cut -f 1 -d ' ' | sort | uniq`
```